# Python program with letters pyramid

Tags: python

I need help with python. I have to do this and I don't know how can I add letters to * pyramid. Thank you [first program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBsn8.jpg) [second program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efbxk.jpg)

Comment: What was your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

```
length = 7          # length of the string
word = "Python"     # string to print

# first program
string = '.' * (length - 1) + word
for i in range(length - 1):
    print(string[i:i + length])

# second program
for i in range(1, length):
    _str = word[:i] + '.' * (length - i)
    print(_str[::-1] + _str)
```

The output is:

```
......P
.....Py
....Pyt
...Pyth
..Pytho
.Python
......PP......
.....yPPy.....
....tyPPyt....
...htyPPyth...
..ohtyPPytho..
.nohtyPPython.
```

Comment: Please don't answer to homework questions. OP didn't even show their attempt.